# having unneeded spaces between lines

Tags: android, sqlite

I am writing my data in a database and getting it in android to set it in a textview but when I write for example:
"hello,
how are you?"

which means each line on a row if the row in the phone completes I get an extra line space and I don't want this need to remove it how can I do that?
thanks.

**EDIT:**
how can I place a line space in an arabic database: I added \n didn't work "\n" didn't work '\n' didn't work!! any ideas?
even if the database wasn't arabic that didn't work so can I place the \n in the database in a way that the android program takes it as a line space?

***Edit2***
Is there any other method? other than the one that I've mentioned in my answer? thanks.

Comment: Insert the problematic layout image in your question.

Comment: it's not from the layout it's from how android is setting data from the database... if I write in a same row several sentence with each sentence seperated from the other by a line space and I get it in android I get an extra line between these sentences even when I write these sentences in the same textview.

Comment: Add some code how you are doing it. Paste the string here if possible in the DB and how you are adding '\n' new line character in the data string.

Answer (score 1):

check to see if you insert to your DB with that extra line.
showing more code would help us understand whats causing your issue...

but if you want to brute force it you could always use `substring()` for each or your elements or

```
 `String  input = EditTextinput.getText().toString();
                      input = input.replace(" ", "");`
```

but like @Nitin Sethi said more code especially the entry to your DB would give us a better understanding of what's going on

Comment: yes thank you, that could work if I didn't need the space but I do need it sometimes so can't replce it with "" I think I should add /n in my db if it will work this will get me spaces the way I need and where I need exactly so I'm gonna try to add /n instead of line space maybe it will work :) thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

so what I did is that I've added the word "line space" in my database and I added 
in my android code:

String  input = //here I take the cde from cursor;
                      input = input.replace("line space", "\n");

and it worked perfectly but is there another way?